# Using axios to make a post request - node js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, axios

I'm new to node.js and i'm trying to do a post request from server side using axios But i get no response data from the request.

If i do a post request from the client side using ajax it works fine and i was just wondering am i doing something wrong?

My server side post request:

```
var postData ={
  a: 'getMessages',
  max: 50,
  id: 5039
};

let postConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  }
};

axios.post('https://url.com/ajax.php', postData, postConfig).then((response) => {
  console.log('response:', response.data);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('error:', error);
});
```

The way i was doing post request from client side:

This worked fine but when i try to do a post request from server side there is no response data.

```
$.post('https://url.com/ajax.php', {
  a: 'getMessages',
  max: 50,
  id: 5039
}, function(response) {
  let data = JSON.parse(response);

  console.log('data:', data);
});
```

Comment: What do you see in `console.log('response:', response.data);`. Or did you enter the catch block?

Comment: I get nothing in the ```response.data```.

Comment: What's the code in ajax.php (there may be a no response path); If you are using a form-encoded header, probably try to use UrlSearchParams object to send your data.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side, it looks like you're using jQuery `$.post()`, which defaults to posting JSON when sending an object like this.

I suspect that the issue is that your content type is sent to be a form.  If you simply get rid of `postConfig` entirely, it should send it as `application/json`, and should properly format the request body for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply/answer but that didn't seem to help me i still get nothing in ```response.data``` .

Comment: @howeve Can you show us the full working request/response raw data from the client?  There's bound to be some other difference.  Maybe you need to set a `User-Agent` header.  Without more information on what you're connecting to, it's hard to help.